# What is the best way change the URL in config file, when updating the application?

Tags: java, rest, client-server, auto-update

I have a javafx client/server application in which the client has a config.ini file where the URL is stored.
I configured the update for Windows in such a way that if there is an update, the program downloads a new jar of the application from the server and then runs the bat script and closes, and bat replaces the jar file. I also need to replace the URL address in config when updating, and all I came up with is just checking and replacing the URL every time I start application.

But this is a very bad decision.

How can I replace the URL only when updating, and at what point is it better to do it?

Comment: Can this not be done by the bat script?

Comment: @Slaw When I wrote the question, this thought came to mind. But I want to know other options.

Comment: whatever the solution, it looks unrelated to javafx

Comment: you could provide a **configuration server** where each client can download its configuration